# T-Algebras for a monad

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring with identity, $G:R$-$Mod\rightarrow Set$ is the forgetful functor and $F:Set\rightarrow R$-$Mod$ its left adjoint. I want to prove that the structure maps for the T-Algebras of the monad $\left \langle GF,G\epsilon F,\eta \right \rangle$ turn sets $X$ into R-modules. As in the semigroup case, in which the structure maps are not a binary operation, but a list of n-ary operations with a recursion that allows sets $X$ to be identified with the object $(X,\ast )$ in $Semigroup$, I am looking for something similar here.

Now, $TX$ is the set of all functions $f:X\rightarrow R$ that are non-zero at at most a finite number of points in $X$. I use the following nomenclature: $f^{x}$ is the function s.t $f^{x}(y)= \delta_{x} ^{y}$, so that if $f\in FX$ then $f=\sum_{k=0} ^{_{n}} a_{k}f^{x_{k}}; a_{k}\in R$.

If $h:TX\rightarrow X$ is a structure map, then it satisfies $h(f^{x})=x$ and, after a rather tedious calculation, I came up with this:

$h(\sum_{k=0} ^{_{n}}a_{k}f^{h(f_{k}))})=h(\sum_{k=0} ^{_{n}} a_{k}f_{k})$ for any $\left \{ f_{k}\in TX: 0\leq k\leq n  \right \}$.

edit: We know $h(f^{x})=x$, and if we use the above formula with the lone function $g$, we get

1). $h(rf^{h(g))})=h(rg)$.

Set $ax+by\equiv h(af^{x}+bf^{y}) $

Now this definition together with  1) shows that the required axioms are satisfied. For example,

$rx+ry\equiv h(rf^{x}+rf^{y})=h(r(f^{x}+f^{y}))=h(rf^{h(f^{x}+f^{y})})\equiv rh(f^{x}+f^{y})=r(x+y)$.

Comment: Well, if $X$ is going to be an $R$-module, then you had better define the module structure so that $h (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k f^{x_k}) = \sum_{k=0} a_k x_k$.